Creating a discriminant function from one known group and one mixed group
I have a dataset composed of captures of individuals (ringed birds), all from the same species. Because the captures took place during spring, summer and autumn, we have trapped breeding and migrating individuals. For a further analysis focusing only on long-distance migrants stopping at the ringing site, I want to start by eliminating from the dataset all birds that were breeding on site or around it.
From what I've seen during the trapping seasons and learned from scientific papers on the subject, I believe that all the birds breeding around the area have shorter wings and longer tarsus than the long-distance ones.
Therefore, I want to create a discriminant function to distinguish local breeders vs long-distance migrants, based on tarsus and wing length.
I was able to add a "breeding" status to all the birds that were known to breed on site (brood patch, cloacal protuberance...), and therefore I ended up with breeding birds forming one group, and another group composed of birds with unknown status, very probably a mix of other birds breeding around the site and long-distance migrants. I already have a significant difference when I look at tarsus length and wing length between the two groups, but there's still some overlap. That makes me believe that there are some birds that could be breeding around the area in the mixed group, but probably not that many.
From what I've looked at regarding discriminant functions, there are always at least two distinct groups. Here, I have one known group and one mixed group. Is there a way (and would it be relevant, reliable?) to create a function "describing" only the known group, and then use it to remove to few breeding birds that are left in the mixed group?
I have 4 years of data, so I was thinking of using two years of "breeding birds" to create the function, and the next two years of "breeding birds" to analyze the probabilities of correct classification.
Any help is welcome,
Thank you!
PS: English is not my native language, so I apologize if it's not super clear!
PS2: using the trapping date is not an option here, for many reasons (huge overlap between the arrival of breeding and migrating birds on site, some birds are residents but don't get trapped often...).

From what I've looked at regarding discriminant functions, there are always at least two distinct groups. This is not what I understood. Submitting two groups to LDA you you can get only one discriminant function (so no "functions"). It can differentiate the two groups well or cannot, but how is about your "at least" two groups? Are you saying of a multimodality in the distribution of the discr. scores? Or what?

Why are you using tag "mixed type data"? Are you saying that the features (such as wing length) from which you extract the discriminant(s) are not all quantitative/scale ones?

Thank you for your comment. I should have been more clear (but all these concepts of discriminant functions are very new to me, and still trying to figure it all out!). One of the paper that pretty much does what I want to do (but has two distinct groups) used a discriminant function analyses (DFA), and ended up with one function for defining breeders and another one for defining migrants. So I guessed I should lean more towards a DFA than a LDA... but it seems the problem regarding my "mixed-group" is the same in both methods

For the "mixed-type-data", I didn't realize : it's a mistake, I wanted to type in "mixed group" but apparently I selected this tag instead.. I'll change that

DFA = DA. It is either linear (LDA) or quadratic (QDA). By "default of the term", DA is LDA.

It sounds to me so from your text, that the breedind status is not what is directly observed but rather is defined by some attributes (such as cloacal protuberance) and is defined not precisely. Otherwise you would not have the "mixed group" where potentially breeding individuals don't have the protuberance etc. Is that so?

Yes, the "breeding" status is defined by attributes, so individuals showing those attributes are definitely breeding on site (young birds still in juvenile plumage are also considered in the same group = I called it here 'breeding' to make it easier but it's actually a sort of "resident at the time t", eg breeding or born on site).  ..->

--> I believe the other group is mixed because, during the migration period, even though some residents have started their reproduction process, the presence of the attributes are not systematically checked, so we could miss some actual breeders by using only the presence of attributes. Also, some birds could stop by the site, present none of these attributes but would actually go to breed not far from that site, and therefore could not be considered as "long-distance migrants", which is the group I want to take into account for further studies. I don't know if that's clearer?

In any way I cannot dip into it, as I am not a specialist in your field of study. But general thing I might say is that it is probably not optimal or at least too early to apply a DA - a modelling technique. Maybe better start with an exploration like cluster analysis or mixture models, to see how natural groups emerge out of your attributes. DA is applicable when you have well established (such as directly observed) groups.

Also, if you insist on doing something like DA but the groups are not mutually exclusive, i.e., they are difined by a set of binary (present-absent) attributes instead of one categorical variable, or by quantitative variables - you might think to do canonical correlation analysis. (Actually, DA is a specific case of CCA.)

Thank you for your answers; I will look into what you've suggested!
